# Send a parameter to an AlertView

Tags: ios, parameters, uialertview

I have a delegate, which recives a message to delete a item with that item as an argument. 
I want to show a confirmation AlertView, and then, if the users press Yes, i want to delete it.

So, what I have is

The delegate method that gets called:

```
- (void) deleteRecording:aRecording(Recording*)aRecording {

     NSLog(@"Cancel recording extended view");
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel recording",nil)
                      message: NSLocalizedString(@"Are you sure you want to cancel the recording?",nil)
                      delegate: self
                      cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"No",nil)
                      otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString(@"Yes",nil), nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

}
```

And the method thats checks which button has been pressed:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    switch (buttonIndex) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSLog(@"Delete was cancelled by the user");
        }
        break;

        case 1:
        {

            NSLog(@"Delete deleted by user");
        }


    }

}
```

So, my question is, how can i send the aRecording parameter from the first method to the second?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Store that variable in a member variable (easiest solution)
2. If you are only passing an int variable, you can set AlertView tag
   property.

   ```
    myAlertView.tag  = YOUR_INT;
   ```
3. > According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html),
   >
   > *Note : The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
   >   private
   >   and must not be modified.*
   >
   > So please use the 3rd method only if you are not intending to submit
   >   app to app store. Thanks user  soemarko ridwan for the tip.

   For passing complex objects, subclass UIAlertView, add an object
   property

   ```
   @interface CustomAlertView : UIAlertView
   @property (nonatomic, retain) id object;
   @end

   @implementation CustomAlertView
   @synthesize object;
   - (void)dealloc {
       [object release];
       [super dealloc];
   }
   @end
   ```

   When you create AlertView

   ```
    CustomAlertView *alert = [[CustomAlertView alloc]
                     initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel recording",nil)
                     message: NSLocalizedString(@"Are you sure you want to cancel the recording?",nil)
                     delegate: self
                     cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"No",nil)
                     otherButtonTitles: NSLocalizedString(@"Yes",nil), nil];
   [alert setObject:YOUR_OBJECT];
   [alert show];
   [alert release];
   ```

   In the delegate

   ```
   - (void)alertView:(TDAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
        NSLog(@"%@", [alertView object]);
   }
   ```

Comment: +1. Good summary. As for 2) - you can associate custom objects to the alert as well, but I'd consider it hackyish...

Comment: 3) One should never subclass UIAlertView. According to the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html): _The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified._

Comment: @soemarkoridwan thanks for the tip.. I am adding it to the answer.. Somehow never read that before..